# C# Generic variable changes if another same type generic changes

Tags: c#, generics, reference, variable-assignment

I've this class:

```
public class Pair<T, V>
{
    public T A = default;
    public V B = default;

    public Pair()
    {
        A = default;
        B = default;
    }

    public Pair(T a, V b)
    {
        A = a;
        B = b;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        Pair<T, V> other = obj as Pair<T, V>;
        return A.Equals(other.A) && B.Equals(other.B);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return base.GetHashCode();
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Pair: (" + A.ToString() + " , " + B.ToString() + ")";
    }
}
```

And I have a class with two Pair variables:

```
public class FakeClass<T>
{
    public T LastValue { get; protected set; } = default;
    public T CurrentValue = default;

    public void Execute() 
    {
         LastValue = CurrentValue
    }
}

public class FakeClassWithPair : FakeClass<Pair<int, int>> { }
```

Now if I execute this code:

```
FakeClassWithPair fake = new FakeClassWithPair();
fake.CurrentValue.A = 2;
fake.CurrentValue.B = 5;
fake.Execute();

fake.CurrentValue.A = 32;
fake.CurrentValue.B = 53;
```

In debugging Current Value and Last Value have the same value "32" and "53".

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 2):

Classes are reference types, so when you set `LastValue = CurrentValue`, that means both LastValue and CurrentValue refer to the *same* object.

If you want [*Value semantics*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-types) you should declare your Pair as a *struct*. This means that an assignment does a copy of the value. Except ofc there already are a built in type for this: [ValueTuple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetuple-2?view=net-6.0), with some special syntax that lets you declare types like `(int A, int B)`. There is also a regular `Tuple<T1, T2>` if you *do* want a reference type.

Also note that I see no way for your example to run, `fake.CurrentValue` should be initialized to null and crash when accessed. Using a value type would also solve this, since they cannot be null.

So just change your example to `FakeClassWithPair:FakeClass<(int A, int B)>` and everything should work as you expect it to.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely do not roll your own **class** for a pair if you want value semantics. Use the built-in value tuple, defined as `(T a, V b)`.

Also if your content of `FakeClass` is cloneable then you should take advantage of that (for example arrays are cloneable). So the assignment in `Execute()` would check if the current value implements `ICloneable` and proceeds accordingly.

See this example code with output. The first example with `fk` variable is defined by `FakeClass<(int,int)>` and the second example with `fa` variable is defined by `FakeClass<int[]>`. Some fun code is added to display arrays as list of vales in `ToString()` in order to mimic the behavior of tuples with arrays.

```
public class FakeClass<T>
{
    public T LastValue { get; protected set; } = default(T);
    public T CurrentValue = default(T);

    public void Execute()
    {
        if (CurrentValue is ICloneable cloneable)
        {
            LastValue = (T)cloneable.Clone();
        }
        else
        {
            LastValue = CurrentValue;
        }
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        if (typeof(T).IsArray)
        {
            object[] last, current;
            Array cv = CurrentValue as Array;
            if (cv != null)
            {
                current = new object[cv.Length];
                cv.CopyTo(current, 0);
            }
            else
            {
                current = new object[0];
            }
            Array lv = LastValue as Array;
            if (lv != null)
            {
                last = new object[lv.Length];
                lv.CopyTo(last, 0);
            }
            else
            {
                last = new object[0];
            }
            
            return $"Current=[{string.Join(",",current)}], Last=[{string.Join(",",last)}]";
        }
        return $"Current={CurrentValue}, Last={LastValue}";
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var fk = new FakeClass<(int a, int b)>();
        fk.CurrentValue = (1, 2);
        Console.WriteLine(fk);
        // Current=(1, 2), Last=(0, 0)
        fk.Execute();
        fk.CurrentValue = (3, 4);
        Console.WriteLine(fk);
        // Current=(3, 4), Last=(1, 2)

        var fa = new FakeClass<int[]>();
        fa.CurrentValue = new int[] { 1, 2 };
        Console.WriteLine(fa);
        //Current=[1,2], Last=[]
        fa.Execute();
        fa.CurrentValue = new int[] { 3, 4 };
        Console.WriteLine(fa);
        //Current=[3,4], Last=[1,2]
    }
}
```

Comment: If I use Tuples (or I make FakeClass as struct) I can't declare FakeClassWithPair and I need it :/

Comment: Why can't you declare `class FakeClassWithPair : FakeClass<(int a,int b)> { }` ?